# How to download zip file from server to client (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, angular, express, blob

I have create a zip file in server side, then I would like to pass the file to client side so that I can download it with the saveAs() function and put it into a new Blob() function. How can I do that?

```
const blob = new Blob([res.file], { type: 'application/zip' });
saveAs(blob, res.filename);
```

I create a code like that, but I cant convert a right type of buffer file for the zip in server.
How should I convert the zip file so that the client side can receive a right file type input in Blob function.

Answer (score 1):

Once you get your zip ready, you can serve the file using `download()` method to achieve that

Below snippet will help you

```
res.download('/report-12345.pdf', 'report.pdf', function (err) {
if (err) {
    // Handle error, but keep in mind the response may be partially-sent
   // so check res.headersSent
 } else {
  // decrement a download credit, etc.
 }
})
```

You can read more details here
http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.download

Hope that will help you :)